Is stroma lamella and intergranal thylakoid the same?
My textbook says that "Thylakoids are arranged in stacks like the piles of coins called grana or the intergranal thylakoids. In addition, there are flat membranous tubules called the stroma lamellae connecting the thylakoids of different grana"
"Grana are connected by stroma thylakoids, also called intergranal thylakoids or lamellae"
"Wrapped around the grana are multiple parallel right-handed helical stromal thylakoids, also known as frets or lamellar thylakoids."
Source: wikipedia

Source: By Yuv345 - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=93345037
This image has stroma lamellar sheets. Is that synonymous to stroma thylakoids?
My confusion is regarding the synonymous terms used.
